# Is it possible to add web fonts in stylesheet where placement of <link> to stylesheet is unknown?

Tags: css, import, stylesheet, webfonts

I am working on changing the styling of pages within a learning platform. The platform allows for the user (me) to use my own CSS to change the styling of pages I myself have created. The problem is that the platform uses som predefined (and unknown to me) CSS before appending their CSS with my CSS. I don't have access to the actual HTML.

Here is the problem: I would like to use web fonts in my CSS. I have therefore been trying to use @import at the start of my CSS. My CSS is appended too late to the predefined CSS for @import to take effect. The only code I can give the system is my own CSS so I can't directly edit the html head to link to the web fonts.

*Is there any other way to add web fonts to my CSS with said CSS being the only code I can write? Is it possible within CSS to append links to the html head?* The support team of the platform consider this is a bug but don't offer a workaround. It would be nice not to have to wait for an update if possible.

Comment: Which platform is it? The exact details of the cascading nature of CSS can be complex, however, the "later" something is included in the file the higher priority it has. Although it is possible that your CSS is being superseded by the platforms CSS, this is probably not the issue.  More likely your CSS is being processed and it is likely that the @import is not permitted. Allowing individuals to inject whatever CSS they please could cause numerous issues. The platform support team will be the best to answer this question.